# Am I misusing a pointer here? While loop conditions don't seem to be working properly

Tags: c++, list, merge, linked-list

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to store a linked list of with nodes that hold a data of any object type. Currently I am building the class with the object type set to Employee (which I'll post below) to simplify the process. After I get all the functions down then I'll convert it into a template.

My problem is I have a "merge" function that takes two sorted lists and then merges them into the calling object list (still sorted). I set up debugging statements "first" "second" "third" and "fourth" just to see which loops were being entered and the cmd prompt goes into an infinite loop of printing "fourth". It's as though neither list ends up with nodes that = NULL, as though they never run off the end... it's quite confusing. Here is the function in question:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// merge
// merges two sorted lists into one sorted list
void List::merge(List* LA, List* LB)
{
   Node* mergedPtr = NULL; //pointer for merged list
   Node* laPtr = LA->head; //pointer for List A
   Node* lbPtr = LB->head; //pointer for List B

   makeEmpty();

   while(laPtr != NULL && lbPtr != NULL)
   {
      if(*laPtr->data <= *lbPtr->data)
      {
         if(head == NULL) //special base case
         {
            head = laPtr;
            mergedPtr = head;
            cout << "first";
         }
         else
         {
            mergedPtr->next = laPtr;
            mergedPtr = mergedPtr->next;
            cout << "second";
         }
         laPtr = laPtr->next; //advance pointer for List A
      }
      else if(*laPtr->data > *lbPtr->data)
      {
         if(head == NULL) //special base case
         {
            head = lbPtr;
            mergedPtr = head;
            cout << "third";
         }
         else
         {
            mergedPtr->next = lbPtr;
            mergedPtr = mergedPtr->next;f
            cout << "fourth";
         }
         lbPtr = lbPtr->next; //advance pointer for List B
      }

      mergedPtr = mergedPtr->next; //advance pointer for merged list
   }

   /*if(laPtr != NULL)
   {
      while(laPtr != NULL)
      {
         mergedPtr->next = laPtr;
         laPtr = laPtr->next;
      }
   }
   else if(lbPtr != NULL)
   {
      while(lbPtr != NULL)
      {
         mergedPtr->next = lbPtr;
         lbPtr = lbPtr->next;
      }
   }*/
}
```

I've rewritten it a few times and tried different methods of tackling the issue but it always seems to have the same problem. Seems to indicate that one of the lists is infinite but in my test class (which I'll post right below) one list has two items and the other has 4... The infile it reads from simply has 4 entries:

Duck Donald 2 35000
Duck Daffy 4 12000
Mouse Mickey 1 100000
Goof Goofy 7 250

In the test class I add an entry then remove it. Then I use a different list to test my makeEmpty() function. Then another list for merge but no results because it catches in an infinite loop within the merge function. Here's the testing class if necessary:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////  listdriver.cpp  //////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Driver for simple linked list
#include "list.h"

// to compile under unix/linux:  g++ nodedata.cpp list.cpp listdriver.cpp

int main() {
   Employee* ptr; 
   List mylist;

   // create file object and open the datafile
   ifstream infile("listdata.txt");
   if (!infile) {
      cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
      return 1;
   }

   // build list from data file 
   mylist.buildList(infile);                 
   cout << "Original list: " << endl << mylist << endl;

   // insert another node where data is pre-determined
   ptr = new Employee("Lee","Law");
   mylist.insert(ptr); 
   cout << " List after insert: " << endl << mylist << endl;

   Employee* temp;
   List testEmpty;
   temp = new Employee("Zebra", "Zee");
   testEmpty.insert(temp);
   temp = new Employee("Jackson", "Jack");
   testEmpty.insert(temp);
   cout << endl << " testEmpty after inserting 2 new employees: " << endl << testEmpty << endl;

   List mergeTest;
   cout << "testtesttest" << endl;
   mergeTest.merge(&testEmpty, &mylist);
   cout << endl << " mergeTest after calling merge(testEmpty, mylist): " << endl << mergeTest << endl;
}
```

Here is the Employee object though I don't think it's relevant to the issue:

```
#include "employee.h"

// incomplete class and not fully documented

//--------------------------  constructor  -----------------------------------
Employee::Employee(string last, string first, int id, int sal) {
   idNumber = (id >= 0 && id <= MAXID? id : -1);
   salary = (sal >= 0 ? sal : -1);
   lastName = last;
   firstName = first;
}   

//--------------------------  destructor  ------------------------------------
// Needed so that memory for strings is properly deallocated
Employee::~Employee() { }

//---------------------- copy constructor  -----------------------------------
   Employee::Employee(const Employee& E) {
      lastName = E.lastName;
      firstName = E.firstName;
      idNumber = E.idNumber;
      salary = E.salary;
   }

//-------------------------- operator= ---------------------------------------
   Employee& Employee::operator=(const Employee& E) {
      if (&E != this) {
         idNumber = E.idNumber;
         salary = E.salary;
         lastName = E.lastName;
         firstName = E.firstName;
      }
      return *this;
   }

//-----------------------------  setData  ------------------------------------
// set data from file
bool Employee::setData(ifstream& inFile) {
   inFile >> lastName >> firstName >> idNumber >> salary;
   return idNumber  >= 0 && idNumber <= MAXID && salary >= 0; 
}

//-------------------------------  <  ----------------------------------------
// < defined by value of name
bool Employee::operator<(const Employee& E) const { 
   return lastName < E.lastName ||
          (lastName == E.lastName && firstName < E.firstName);
}


//-------------------------------  <= ----------------------------------------
// < defined by value of inamedNumber
bool Employee::operator<=(const Employee& E) const { 
   return *this < E || *this == E;
}

//-------------------------------  >  ----------------------------------------
// > defined by value of name
bool Employee::operator>(const Employee& E) const { 
   return lastName > E.lastName ||
          (lastName == E.lastName && firstName > E.firstName);
}

//-------------------------------  >= ----------------------------------------
// < defined by value of name
bool Employee::operator>=(const Employee& E) const { 
   return *this > E || *this == E;
}

//----------------- operator == (equality) ----------------
// if name of calling and passed object are equal,
//   return true, otherwise false
//
bool Employee::operator==(const Employee& E) const {
   return lastName == E.lastName && firstName == E.firstName;
}

//----------------- operator != (inequality) ----------------
// return opposite value of operator==
bool Employee::operator!=(const Employee& E) const {
   return !(*this == E);
}

//-------------------------------  <<  ---------------------------------------
// display Employee object

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Employee& E) { 
   output << setw(4) << E.idNumber << setw(7) << E.salary << "  " 
          << E.lastName << " " << E.firstName << endl; 
   return output;
}
```

I wouldn't be too surprised if someone pointed out that the issue isn't with merge but elsewhere... That's why I'm posting the rest of the class code here below (I expect it will be asked for). The thing is though I don't see any connections with any other functions within the class. The test driver I use insert and remove but it's with a node that falls within the center of the list so it wouldn't fuck up any pointers to NULL that exist on the end... There are two versions of the merge function listed below. The lower one is commented out but not sure how visible that is on this thread. Any hints would be appreciated. I've hit a roadblock :l

```
////////////////////////////////  list.cpp file  /////////////////////////////

#include "list.h"

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Constructor 
List::List()
{
   head = NULL;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copy Constructor 
/*List::List(const List &other)
{

}*/

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Destructor 
// Can just call makeEmpty()
List::~List()
{
   makeEmpty();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// retrieve
// retrieves an object from the list
bool List::retrieve(Employee* target, Employee* other)
{
   if (isEmpty())
   {
      other = NULL;
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      Node* ptr = head;

      while(ptr != NULL && ptr->data != target)
      {
         ptr = ptr->next;
      }
      if(ptr == NULL)
      {
         return false;
      }

      other = ptr->data;
      return true;
   }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// remove
// remove an object from the list
bool List::remove(Employee* target, Employee* other) 
{
   if (isEmpty()) 
   {
      other = NULL;
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      Node* ptr = head;
      Node* lastPtr = NULL;

      while(ptr != NULL && ptr->data != target) 
      {
         lastPtr = ptr;
         ptr = ptr->next;
      }
      if(ptr == NULL) 
      {
         return false;
      }

      other = ptr->data;
      lastPtr->next = ptr->next; // skips over target for list pointers
      delete ptr; //deletes now obsolete node from the list and memory
      return true;
   }
}



//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// isEmpty 
// check to see if List is empty
bool List::isEmpty() const 
{
   return head == NULL;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// makeEmpty 
// empty out the list, deallocate all memory for all Nodes and each Object
void List::makeEmpty()
{
   Node* tempPtr;

   while(head != NULL)
   {
      tempPtr = head;
      delete head->data;
      head = tempPtr->next;
      delete tempPtr;
   }   
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// insert 
// insert an item into list; operator< of the NodeData class
// has the responsibility for the sorting criteria
bool List::insert(Employee* dataptr) 
{                    

   Node* ptr = new Node;
   if (ptr == NULL) return false;                 // out of memory, bail
   ptr->data = dataptr;                           // link the node to data

   // if the list is empty or if the node should be inserted before 
   // the first node of the list
   if (isEmpty() || *ptr->data < *head->data) 
   {
      ptr->next = head;                           
      head = ptr;
   }

   // then check the rest of the list until we find where it belongs 
   else {

      Node* current = head->next;          // to walk list
      Node* previous = head;               // to walk list, lags behind

      // walk until end of the list or found position to insert
      while (current != NULL && *current->data < *ptr->data) 
      {
            previous = current;                  // walk to next node
            current = current->next;
      }

      // insert new node, link it in
      ptr->next = current; 
      previous->next = ptr; 
   }
   return true;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// merge
// merges two sorted lists into one sorted list
void List::merge(List* LA, List* LB)
{
   Node* mergedPtr = NULL; //pointer for merged list
   Node* laPtr = LA->head; //pointer for List A
   Node* lbPtr = LB->head; //pointer for List B

   makeEmpty();

   while(laPtr != NULL && lbPtr != NULL)
   {
      if(*laPtr->data <= *lbPtr->data)
      {
         if(head == NULL) //special base case
         {
            head = laPtr;
            mergedPtr = head;
            cout << "first";
         }
         else
         {
            mergedPtr->next = laPtr;
            mergedPtr = mergedPtr->next;
            cout << "second";
         }
         laPtr = laPtr->next; //advance pointer for List A
      }
      else if(*laPtr->data > *lbPtr->data)
      {
         if(head == NULL) //special base case
         {
            head = lbPtr;
            mergedPtr = head;
            cout << "third";
         }
         else
         {
            mergedPtr->next = lbPtr;
            mergedPtr = mergedPtr->next;f
            cout << "fourth";
         }
         lbPtr = lbPtr->next; //advance pointer for List B
      }

      mergedPtr = mergedPtr->next; //advance pointer for merged list
   }

   /*if(laPtr != NULL)
   {
      while(laPtr != NULL)
      {
         mergedPtr->next = laPtr;
         laPtr = laPtr->next;
      }
   }
   else if(lbPtr != NULL)
   {
      while(lbPtr != NULL)
      {
         mergedPtr->next = lbPtr;
         lbPtr = lbPtr->next;
      }
   }*/
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// merge
// merges two sorted lists into one sorted list
/*void List::merge(List LA, List LB)
{
   //merge sort - take first element from each list, compare, higher value goes first; continue until done sorting
   List* Temp = new List(); //define a new list to be merged into
   Node* LAA = LA.head;
   Node* LBB = LB.head;

   //special case: first copied element is set as head
   if(Temp->head == NULL)
   {
      Node* tempNode;

      cout << "code test: first" << endl;
      if(LAA->data <= LBB->data)
      {
         tempNode = LAA;
         Temp->head = tempNode;
         LAA = LAA->next;
      } 
      else
      {
         tempNode = LBB;
         Temp->head = tempNode;
         LBB = LBB->next;
      }
   }
   cout << "code test: second" << endl;

   //rest of lists
   Node* tempPtr;
   while(LAA != NULL && LBB != NULL)
   {
      tempPtr = Temp->head;
      if(LAA->data <= LBB->data)
      {
         tempPtr->next = LAA;
         LAA = LAA->next;
      }
      else
      {
         tempPtr->next = LBB;
         LBB = LBB->next;
      }
   }
   cout << "code test: third" << endl;

   //catches the remainder extra from either list (messy solution)
   if(LAA != NULL)
   {
      while(LAA != NULL)
      {
         tempPtr->next = LAA;
         LAA = LAA->next;
      }
   }
   if(LBB != NULL)
   {
      while(LBB != NULL)
      {
         tempPtr->next = LBB;
         LBB = LBB->next;
      }
   }
   cout << "code test: fourth" << endl;

}*/

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// intersect
// takes the common nodes from two lists and sorts them into a new list
void List::intersect(List* LA, List* LB)
{
   List* temp = new List();
   Node* tempPtr = NULL;
   Node* LAPtr = LA->head;
   Node* LBPtr = LB->head;

   while(LAPtr != NULL && LBPtr != NULL)
   {
      while(LAPtr->data < LBPtr->data)
      {
         LAPtr = LAPtr->next;
      }
      while(LAPtr->data > LBPtr->data)
      {
         LBPtr = LBPtr->next;
      }
      //base case when new list is empty
      if(LAPtr->data == LBPtr->data && temp->head == NULL)
      {
         temp->head = LAPtr;
         tempPtr = head;
         LAPtr = LAPtr->next;
         LBPtr =LBPtr->next;
      }
      //create new node copying the common node and add it to the end of the new list
      //advance the list pointers
      if(LAPtr->data == LBPtr->data)
      {
         Node* tempNode = new Node;
         tempNode->data = LAPtr->data;
         tempNode->next = NULL;
         tempPtr->next = tempNode;
         LAPtr = LAPtr->next;
         LBPtr =LBPtr->next;
      }

   }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// buildList 
// continually insert new items into the list
void List::buildList(ifstream& infile) 
{
   Employee* ptr;
   bool successfulRead;                            // read good data
   bool success;                                   // successfully insert
   for (;;) 
   {
      ptr = new Employee;
      successfulRead = ptr->setData(infile);       // fill the NodeData object
      if (infile.eof()) 
      {
         delete ptr;
         break;
      }

      // insert good data into the list, otherwise ignore it
      if (successfulRead) 
      {
         success = insert(ptr);
      }
      else 
      {
         delete ptr;
      }
      if (!success) break;
   }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// operator<<  
// output operator for class List, print data, 
// responsibility for output is left to object stored in the list
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const List& thelist) 
{

   List::Node* current = thelist.head;
   while (current != NULL) 
   { 
      output << *current->data;
      current = current->next;
   }
   return output;                      // enables output << x << y;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// operator=  
// sets one list equal to another
List& List::operator=(const List &other)
{
   if(this == &other)
      return *this;
   Node* tempPtr;

   while(head != NULL) //copy of makeEmpty code; empties the list for new data to be entered
   {
      tempPtr = head;
      delete head->data;
      head = tempPtr->next;
      delete tempPtr;
   }
   tempPtr = other.head; //to navigate other list
   head = tempPtr;
   Node* disPtr; //to build this list
   disPtr = head;
   while(tempPtr->next != NULL)
   {
      Node* temp = new Node;
      disPtr->next = temp; //creates a copy of node
      disPtr->next->data = tempPtr->next->data;
      disPtr->next->next = tempPtr->next->next;

      disPtr = disPtr->next;
      tempPtr = tempPtr->next;
   }

   return *this;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// operator==
// checks if two lists are the same
bool List::operator==(List* LB)
{
   Node* LAPtr = head;
   Node* LBPtr = LB->head;
   while(LAPtr != NULL && LBPtr != NULL)
   {
      if(LAPtr->data != LBPtr->data)
      {
         return false;
      }
      LAPtr = LAPtr->next;
      LBPtr = LBPtr->next;
      if(LAPtr->data == NULL && LBPtr->data != NULL)
      {
         return false;
      }
      if (LAPtr->data == NULL && LBPtr->data != NULL)
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// operator!=
// checks if two lists are not the same
bool List::operator!=(List* LB)
{
   Node* LAPtr = head;
   Node* LBPtr = LB->head;
   while(LAPtr != NULL && LBPtr != NULL)
   {
      if(LAPtr->data == LBPtr->data)
      {
         return false;
      }
      LAPtr = LAPtr->next;
      LBPtr = LBPtr->next;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: tldr - try to provide a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Trimmed my testdriver down so that it only has two lists and then the merge call. I can't really trim anything else... the last two blocks of code are just for reference since every time I ask a question generally some people want the entire class as reference. The issue is with the first code block which is the function so I can't exactly trim that down either.

Comment: If you simply create a list of floats you don't need to show us your Employee class. Cut all unused functionality from your List class (like operator..., intersect, buildlist). Stop reading the list from a file and just fill it in code. Ideally, thoroughly test your list class to make sure it works and then don't show it to us at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
    mergedPtr = mergedPtr->next;
```

twice. This will result in undefined behavior.
Also, you should use nullptr instead of NULL.